# Cypress Using fixture in test

Tags: cypress

I want to use fixture in all my tests. I have my fixture file ‘comptes_qualifs’ like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw4ya.png)

In my JS script, I added in the beforeEach part, the loading of the fixture file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e5av.png)

So in one my test, I want to use the login of the compte_i variable like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IZC1.png)

But when I launch the test, I have this error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/untTK.png)

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access something from the fixture file I prefer this option:

Before the `describe`add:

```js
import {comptes_qualif} from "{{path relative to your spec file}}/comptes_qualif"
const compte = new comptes_qualif()
```

Now you can call the login value from your fixture file using:

```js
compte.compte_i.login
```

`this` only works for anything defined inside this spec file. If it is defined in a fixture or pages file (even after you import it at the beginning), you still have to call it with a name that you have to defined as `const`, e.g. `compte`in my example

Comment: Are you sure the `log` command support aliases? The docs says nothing about aliases for `cy.log`

Comment: Yes, I have used that a couple of times already when I wanted to make sure that I have stored the right value/string. In some specs I need to save a value in an alias for later and during testing I always include a ```cy.log('@alias')``` in my script.
Of course, because of the asynchronous nature of Cypress, you can only log it in a ```it``` later instance, not in the same instance where you stored it

Comment: could you provide the full example?
I've just tried   `cy.wrap("asdf").as("alias").then(() => {
      cy.log("@alias")
    })` and got `log @alias` in the output

Comment: I edited my answer a bit. In order to log an alias you can try this ```describe('alias', () => {
    it('save alias', () => {
        cy.wrap('This is a test').then((text) => {
           cy.wrap(text).as('text') cy.log(text);
        })
    })
})``` Now you can use the alias ```text``` later